# SPFX provisioning list, how to index column?

Tags: list, spfx, provisioning

I need to provision a list with my SPFX app.   How do I set column indexes on some of these list fields as part of the provisioning?  Is that even possible?
**The fields I need to index will be part of a custom content type (already existing).

Thank you,
Powell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in the XML definition of the column to make the parameter Indexed="TRUE". That way once it's added to the list it will automatically appear as indexed on the list.